# Use Shinyapps.io authentication to validate user profiles

Tags: r, shiny, shinyapps

I was wondering if it's possible to use the internal ShinyApps.io authentication method to validate different user profiles within a Shiny app. This authentication method is available from the standard plan onwards and uses an invitation system through mail to grant access to the application. (The invited users would need to create an account on Shinyapps.io if they don't have one.)

By different user profiles I mean that depending on the accesing user, some elements on the app can be visible or not, or different datasets to be used, etc.

I've used packages such as Shinymanager that allow the control of user profiles, password management, etc. With this package, I've managed to assign different roles to the users by using an ObserveEvent as a validation process to select which data to show. A reproducible example can be as follows:

```
library(shiny)
library(shinymanager)
library(dplyr)

#Credentias df
creds <- data.frame(user = c('user1','user2'),
                    password = c('pass1','pass2'),
                    df = c('iris','cars')
                    )

#UI
ui <- fluidPage(
  uiOutput('title'),
  tableOutput('table')
)


#Shiny manager authentication UI
ui <- secure_app(ui, language = 'en')


#SERVER
server <- function(input, output) {
  
  #Reactive values to store the data
  reac_v <- reactiveValues()
  
  #Shiny manager credentials check
  res_auth <- secure_server(check_credentials = check_credentials(creds))
  
  #ObserveEvent to validate user profile, select the data, and store it in reac_v
  observeEvent(res_auth,{
    x <- reactiveValuesToList(res_auth)
    
    if(length(x) > 0){
      
      user <- x$user
      title <- paste0('This is the ',user)
      validator <- x$df
      
      df <- switch(validator,
                   iris = head(iris),
                   cars = head(cars))
      
      reac_v$title <- title
      reac_v$df <- df
      
    }
    
  })
  
  #Outputs
  output$title <- renderText(reac_v$title)
  output$table <- renderTable(reac_v$df)
  
}

shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```

It's possible to use a similar validation process for user profiles without Shinymanager but using the ShinyApps.io internal authentication instead? If so, what approach or method should be used?

Appreciated!

Comment: See `session$user` https://shiny.posit.co/r/reference/shiny/1.7.3/session.html